# Python age guessing game

Tags: python-2.7

I am trying to create a game that will guess your age.  I got it to work but I can only go up in increments of 1. I would like to get it to start off in higher increments and get lower. If i add an additional if statement my game breaks.

```
x = 25

print"I am going to guess your age"

print("Are you " +\
      str(x) + \
      ", or are you older or younger? " )

guess = raw_input()

while guess != "yes":

      if guess == "older":
            x = x + 1
            print(x)
            guess = raw_input("Are you " +\
                              str(x) +\
                              ", or are you older or younger? " + "\n")
      elif guess == "younger":
            x = x - 1
            print(x)
            guess = raw_input("Are you " +\
                              str(x) +\
                              ", or are you older or younger? " + str(x) + "\n")
print"I got it, you are " + str(x)
```

Comment: Can you show us the code you tried to change the increments (i.e., the code that broke the game). Also show the full error (traceback) that comes with it.

Comment: I was putting in two if statements so it would work on the first cycle through but would not let me choose "younger" once I was on the "older" if statement.

Answer (score 0):

How about adding a second counter... This is not great but just to get you started....

```
x = 25
y = 20
print"I am going to guess your age"

print("Are you " +\
  str(x) + \
  ", or are you older or younger? " )

guess = raw_input()

while guess != "yes":

  if guess == "older":
        x = x + y
        y = y/2
        print(x)
        guess = raw_input("Are you " +\
                          str(x) +\
                          ", or are you older or younger? " + "\n")
  elif guess == "younger":
        x = x - y
        y = y/2
        print(x)
        guess = raw_input("Are you " +\
                          str(x) +\
                          ", or are you older or younger? " + str(x) + "\n")
print"I got it, you are " + str(x)
```

Edits, changed y from 5 to 20, and changed y = y - 1 to y = y /2 now it works like expected.

Little better but this one will reask the same number

```
x = 25
y = 10
print"I am going to guess your age"

print("Are you " +\
  str(x) + \
  ", or are you older or younger? " )

guess = raw_input()
previousGuess = ""
while guess != "yes":

  if guess == "older":
        x = x + y
        if guess != previousGuess :
            y = y/2
        print(x)
        previousGuess = guess
        guess = raw_input("Are you " +\
                          str(x) +\
                          ", or are you older or younger? " + "\n")
  elif guess == "younger":
        x = x - y
        if guess != previousGuess :
            y = y/2
        print(x)
        previousGuess = guess
        guess = raw_input("Are you " +\
                          str(x) +\
                          ", or are you older or younger? " + str(x) + "\n")
print"I got it, you are " + str(x)
```

Comment: Thanks Dan, I added your code and changed x = 45 and y = 40. It works pretty good. Thanks a lot.